figma plugin How to implement connectors and other nodes that can only be used in figjam mode in figma mode
I want to implement figma plugin to realize that the connector and other nodes in figjam mode can be used in figma mode instead of copying and pasting them into figma mode in figjam mode.
Can I get the data stored in some figjam nodes, thereby eliminating the step of copying to figjam mode and reading the data directly to the clipboard? The question is how do I get these node data and store them so that figma can recognize them as nodes after copying and pasting them?
